# Why is the == operator (defined for the concrete type) not used?

Tags: c#, operator-overloading

I have a list defined as:

```
var Items = new List<IItem>();
```

Now there are a number of different classes that have that interface and one of them is Consumable.  The Consumable class also has the == operator overloaded.  Now I have the following code and is not working:

```
if(item1 == item2)
{
    //code...
}
```

This does not work.  I put a break point in the == operator overload and it never gets to it.  When I go through line-by-line debugging, both item1 and item2 are of type Consumable, both GetType returns Consumable.  I even try this code:

```
var temp = item1.GetType();
var temp2 = item2.GetType();
if (temp == temp2)
{
    //code...
}
```

and this equality results is true.  Now if I try this:

```
if(((Consumable)item1) == ((Consumable)item2))
{
    //code...
}
```

and this triggers the break point in the == operator overload.  Why would I have to manually cast the variable if when line-by-line debugging show it already thinks they are both consumable?  Is it because I am pulling them from a list of IItems?

Comment: Marc is right; for some more thoughts on this design decision, see my article on the subject: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/09/double-your-dispatch-double-your-fun.aspx

Answer (score 10):

Since your list is `List<IItem>`, I'm assuming you have something like:

```
var item1 = Items[0];
```

or whatever; here `item1` **the variable** is typed as `IItem`. Operator resolution happens during build via static analysis (not at runtime via polymorphism/RTTI), so the only `==` available is the default for any `object`, i.e. reference equality.

To support your custom operator, the **variables** must be typed accordingly, for example:

```
Consumable item1 = ..., item2 = ...;
```

Your cast achieves a similar thing.

Another option would be to make sure that `==` and `Equals` (and `GetHashCode()`) are in agreement, and use:

```
if(Equals(item1, item2)) {...}
```

which will do `null` checks and then use your overridden `Equals` method. This then supports polymorphism, so it doesn't matter what the types are.

Answer (score 1):

The common langauge runtime does only know that your two objects implement the interface IItem. The smallest common part in object hierarchy is System.Object. And you did not overload the == operator of System.Object.

To use the correct overload you have to state the type of the object.

Answer (score 0):

== does not check type equality, but for classes it checks reference equality. So if the variables are pointing to the same object it will be true. For example like this:

```
var temp = item1;
var temp2 = item1;

if( temp == temp2 )
{
  //this code will execute
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't be the IItem IComparable?

Comment: `IComparable` is for sorting, not equality. The inbuilt `Equals` is for equality, as is `IEquatable<T>` if you want a typed API.